How can I encrypt my python application which has several .py files & .dat files to host on windows server, so that no one can access my code?
I have several Python applications like Django APIs, Flask APIs, Python backend services, etc. Due to some reasons, I have to host these applications as-is on a Windows server. How do I secure my source code, so that no one can access/view it?
